# Azure Classic VM Migration

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, migration

Our cloud product has been transferred to another company. This company have their own Azure subscription and I need to transfer all the services to the new subscription. The cloud service includes an Azure SQL Database, a Cloud Service (classic, with 1 web role and 1 worker role), a storage account (classic) and VM (classic) running SQL Server with Reporting Services.

Our CI/CD server has been configured to deploy the database and cloud services. The storage service is being transferred using AzCopy.

The problem I have is, I don't have the details to reconfigure a Reporting Server. I have taken a copy of the VHDs (whilst the machine was switched off, but not sysprepped) and copied them to the new storage service. I need to find a way to create a new classic VM and attach the two VHDs to it without disrupting the existing environment. Once the environment has passed testing, the current environment will be torn down. Because the VM is a "classic" model, the Azure portal will not transfer it to another subscription. I'd like to avoid sysprepping the current live reporting server if possible because I cannot afford to disrupt the current service.

I have read a lot on here but most of it seems to apply to later (non-classic) VMs and refers to "managed" and "unmanaged" disks, which I don't understand. There are scripts that create virtual networks, etc. that the current environment does not seem to have anything comparable.

I'm hoping someone can help me with the easiest way to transfer this VM?

Comment: If you have a copy of the relevant VHD's in the new subscription why not create a new VM and attach these VHD's? You can then run Sysprep if needed on the new VM. Alternately, download the VHD's to your local environment, create a VM with these VHD's, Sysprep the VM and then upload the VHD's back to your subscription? Or perhaps I'm not quite understanding what you need to do.

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for your comment. The bit I'm struggling with is when I use the portal to create a new VM I can't find a method that allows me to just create an empty, blank VM with no disks. The only thing I can see are templates for existing models. Do you know of a way to create a blank VM and attach the VHDs?

Comment: Admittedly, I don't use Azure that much, but this should (hopefully) help. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-image

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks Joe for the initial idea to download to Hyper. I'll combine your advice with that of Walter and see how I get on.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your scenario, if you want your original VMs and  new VMs exist at the same time, you need to execute `sysprep`. Now, you could not execute on original VMs, I suggest you could download the VM's VHDs to your local and use the VHD to create new VM in Hyper, then you could execute `sysprep`. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Download your original VM's VHD to your local PC from Azure, you could use [Azcopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

2.Create a new VM in Hyper, you could refer to this [link](https://www.petri.com/download-azure-vm-hyper-v).

3.On Hyper VM, you need to execute [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/capture-image#capture-the-virtual-machine).

4.Upload VHD to Azure classic storage account. **Important: If using AzCopy to copy the VHD from local storage to Azure Storage, make sure you specify `/BlobType:Page` for the copy.**

5.Create a new Image on classic Portal.

[image]

6.Create new VM on Azure with your Image.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to give this approach a try. I have started the VHDs downloading. Once they're down I'll try creating an instance in Hyper, sysprepping it and re-upload it to Azure. Thanks for your detailed instructions. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: OK, what is progress now?

Comment: Unfortunately, the download failed with a "Could Not Finish the Operation Within Specified Timeout" message. One of the VHDs is 1TB (it's not full). I've seen some advice about reducing the number of threads AzCopy is using and am trying that.

Comment: Yes, according to the error, it seems download timeout. You had better improve your network environment.

Comment: I've managed to get the disks down. Having sysprepped the OS I rebooted it to see what impact sysprep would have on the environment. I haven't completely got SSRS responding and need to get help from a colleague on this so, I've sysprepped the original download again and am attempting to upload it back to Azure to complete your instructions. I'm working from home and whilst my download speed is 200Mbps, my upload is 20Mbps. If it fails, I may need to sysprep the original server anyway. Hopefully, if I do this, I can migrate the VHD and immediately restore the server from the Backup Vault.

Comment: An important thing to know, before waiting 24 hours for the blob to upload, is that it must be a Page blob type, not a Block. There's no way to change it once it's there so I've got to start the upload again. I'll let you know how it goes this time. I will accept your answer if it solves the problem. :)

Comment: What ways you use to upload your VHD. You could use `Add-AzureVhd -Destination "https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<ContainerName>/<vhdName>.vhd" -LocalFilePath <LocalPathtoVHDFile>` Please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/createupload-vhd#step-3-upload-the-vhd-file).

Comment: Using AzCopy you need to use the /BlobType parameter to specify Page type. I didn't notice the VHDs in Azure are Page type and the default behaviour for AzCopy, when copying from local storage, is Blob type. However, I was able to get around the 24 hour re-upload scenario by copying the file to File Storage and back to Blob Storage on another Azure VM (where it went across at 40MB/s!). The rest of your instructions have worked though. I now have a copy of the VM up and running. There are a few issues to iron out but the machine is basically there and nearly working. Thank you for your help.